# how to use spark with python or jupyter notebook

Tags: python, windows, apache-spark, pyspark, distributed-computing

I am trying to work with 12GB of data in python for which I desperately need to use Spark , but I guess I'm too stupid to use command line by myself or by using internet and that is why I guess I have to turn to SO ,

So by far I have downloaded the spark and unzipped the tar file or whatever that is ( sorry for the language but I am feeling stupid and out ) but now I can see nowhere to go.  I have seen the instruction on spark website documentation and it says :

**Spark also provides a Python API. To run Spark interactively in a Python interpreter, use** `bin/pyspark`  but where to do this ? please please help . 
Edit : I am using windows 10

Note:: I have always faced problems when trying to install something mainly because I can't seem to understand Command prompt

Comment: Have you used Spark before? It's RDD type interface isn't the most intuitive tools out there. If you used Pandas before, how about trying SFrames? It can load any size of data (larger than your RAM), but slower than Pandas. Syntax is almost the same as Pandas.

Comment: no i need to use spark because my team uses it and i have to submit a project after analysis by monday

Answer (score 3):

If you are more familiar with jupyter notebook, you can install [Apache Toree](https://toree.incubator.apache.org/documentation/user/quick-start)  which integrates pyspark,scala,sql and SparkR kernels with Spark.

for installing toree

```
pip install toree
jupyter toree install --spark_home=path/to/your/spark_directory --interpreters=PySpark
```

if you want to install other kernels you can use

```
jupyter toree install --interpreters=SparkR,SQl,Scala
```

Now  run

```
jupyter notebook
```

In the UI while selecting new notebook, you should see following kernels availble

```
Apache Toree-Pyspark
Apache Toree-SparkR
Apache Toree-SQL
Apache Toree-Scala
```

Comment: i was able to install after a few problems , but i guess i will try your's method on a different machine , thanks

Comment: @AnuragPandey that's good news! Make sure you accept an answer after your attempt(s)! :)

Answer (score 1):

When you unzip the file, a directory is created.

1. Open a terminal.
2. Navigate to that directory with `cd`.
3. Do an `ls`. You will see its contents. `bin` must be placed
   somewhere.
4. Execute `bin/pyspark` or maybe `./bin/pyspark`.

Of course, in practice it's not that simple, you may need to set some paths, like said in [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_spark/apache_spark_installation.htm), but there are plenty of such links out there.

Comment: thanks for the answer can i walk with you while i install it ? please that will be a big help . if you want we can chat

Comment: @AnuragPandey I know how you feel. Unfortunately, I cannot, I am at my work. I you found this helpful, accept it. If you phase problems, post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have already installed Spark in the windows 10.

You will need to have winutils.exe available as well. If you haven't already done so,  download the file from http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/hdp-win-alpha/winutils.exe and install at say, C:\winutils\bin

Set up environment variables

```
HADOOP_HOME=C:\winutils
SPARK_HOME=C:\spark or wherever.
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython or jupyter notebook
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook
```

Now navigate to the C:\Spark directory in a command prompt and type "pyspark"

Jupyter notebook will launch in a browser.
Create a spark context and run a count command as shown.

[image]